# Java/Spring - reconnect to DB

Tags: java, spring, runtime, database-connection, autowired

I have a Java/Spring/Hibernate project, that has a connection to a Vertica DB. Occasionally, the connection dies due to some environmental issues, and i am trying to re-establish the connection during the runtime. The problem is that the original  connection, that is @Autowired into repositories is not getting updated and remains pointing to the original "dead" connection.

The original connection is created as @Bean via config during the server start.

Config:

```
package com.myproject.configs
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class dbConfig {


@Value("${db.jdbcUrl}")
private String connectionString;

@Value("${db.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${db.password}")
private String password;

@Bean(name = "dbConnection", destroyMethod = "close")
public Connection dbConn() throws SQLException {
   Properties myProp = new Properties();
   myProp.put("user", username);
   myProp.put("password", password);

   Connection conn;
   try {
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, myProp);
      return conn;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      log.error("Cannot establish DB connection");
      throw e;
   }
}
```

}

Usage:

```
    @Repository
    @Slf4j
    public class SomeDbRepository {

    @Autowired
    Connection dbConnection;
    ...
```

Now, i need to monitor whether an incoming API request will actually reach the DB, so i want to check all incoming requests in an interceptor and then if the connection is not responding, re-establish it.

So, i use context to get the bean and run the dbConn() again:

```
  package com.myproject.interceptors;
    import com.myproject.configs.DbConfig;
    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import java.sql.*;
    @Component
    @Slf4j
    public class DbConnectionCheckInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter { 
    @Autowired
    Connection dbConnection;
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

   @Override
   public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
try {
           Statement stmt = dbConnection.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 1;");
           rs.next();
           return true;
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           try {
               DbConfig dbConfig = context.getBean(DbConfig.class);
    // *** here i am trying to re-establish the connection by accessing the bean through context ***
               dbConfig.dbConn();
               return true;
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               log.error("Couldn't connect to DB", ex);
               return false;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you need to refresh this connection, you can do away with Using spring bean, maybe you can use a static method to get the connection object (instead of bean), which has your reconnection logic (if required) else it returns the pre-populated DB connection object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. Eventually, we have solved the issue by refactoring the connection config bean to approach that uses DataSource with JdbcTemplate + hikari connection pool. Now, Hikari is  taking care of connections and re-connects to the DB if needed.

**Config bean:**

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class VerticaConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.jdbcUrl}")
    private String connectionString;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClassName;


    @Bean(name = "verticaDataSource", destroyMethod = "close")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource verticaDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName(driverClassName)
                .url(connectionString)
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "verticaJdbcTemplate")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate verticaJdbcTemplate() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(verticaDataSource());
    }
}
```

Hikari config:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.vertica.jdbc.Driver
    jdbcUrl:  jdbc:vertica://abc
    username: ***
    password: ***
    # hikari config
    maxLifetime: 300000 #5 min default 30 min
    poolName: my-connection-pool
    maximumPoolSize: 5
    minimum-idle: 3
    connectionTimeout: 59000
    validationTimeout: 10000
    idleTimeout: 240000 #4 min  default 10 min
    leakDetectionThreshold: 59000
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a Java Class - DBConnection

:

```
public class DBConnection {
private Connection conn;
private String connString;
private Properties myProp;    
public Connection getConn() {
    return conn;
}

public DBConnection(String userName, String pwd, String connString) {
    myProp = new Properties();
    myProp.put("user", username);
    myProp.put("password", password);
    this.connString = connString;
    try{
        setConn();
    }catch (Exception e){
        log.error("DB connection failed", e);
    }
}

public void setConn() throws SQLException {
    try {
        //Properly close the existing connection before procuring new one. Check if conn not null and close accordingly 
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, myProp);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Cannot establish DB connection", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

2. Bean creation

   ```
    @Bean(name = "dbConnection")
    public Connection dbConn() throws SQLException {
       return new DBConnection(username, password, connectionString);
    }
   ```
3. Now, you can autowire DBConnection and for any SQL execution, you can get the connection from this bean - dbConnection.getConn() for executing any SQL statement.
4. In preHandle, you can simply do dbConnection.setConn(). Any SQL statement execution, will try to refer same bean -  dbConnection.getConn() but the conn object within it would have got refreshed.